# ANOVA + follow-up using repeated measures design with a modification

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I want to compare performance of strategies on a group of tasks. I determine performance by running simulations, so I can independently run every strategy on each task (repeated measures):

```
strategy_A  task_1  result_sA_t1
strategy_A  task_2  result_sA_t2
strategy_A  task_3  result_sA_t3


strategy_B  task_1  result_sB_t1
strategy_B  task_2  result_sB_t2
strategy_B  task_3  result_sB_t3


strategy_C  task_1  result_sC_t1
strategy_C  task_2  result_sC_t2
strategy_C  task_3  result_sC_t3
```

There is a random component in the strategies, so I decided to modify the standard design and run every simulation 7 times:

```
strategy_A  task_1  result_sA_t1_1
strategy_A  task_1  result_sA_t1_2
.
.
.
strategy_A  task_1  result_sA_t1_7

strategy_A  task_2  result_sA_t2_1
.
.
.
strategy_A  task_2  result_sA_t2_7

strategy_A  task_3  result_sA_t3_1
.
.
.
strategy_A  task_3  result_sA_t3_7

(the same for strategy_B and C)
```

I have found a number of blog posts ([post_1](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/), [post_2](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/repeated.html)) describing how to perform ANOVA and follow-up Tukey's test in R, but they all assumed that there is only one datapoint for a strategy-task pair, while I have 7 of them. How can use R's ANOVA and Tukey's test to analyse my data?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach:

Use `aov` with `Error(simulation/(Strategy * Task))`.

This is easier if you [tidy your data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) first. Organize your data to look like this:

```
Strategy    Task    Simulation    Performance
A           1       1             105
A           1       2             102
...         ...     ...           ...
C           3       7             92
```

Then, `aov(Performance ~ Strategy * Task + Error(Simulation/(Strategy * Task)), data)`.

I'll leave the Tukey test for someone else. You could also do a bunch of repeated measures t-tests.

Comment: Thank you - I have read somewhere that just using t-tests when comparing multiple strategies (well, they write about therapies or sth. mostly) could give more false positives, so I want to use Tukey's.